# Regular Expressions - What is difference between a+ and a⁺

Tags: regular-languages, automata, regular-expressions

I'm very confused as to if a+ and a⁺ mean the same thing or are completely different.

Comment: It should be noted that, when you're dealing with practical implementations of regular expression syntax, the `^` symbol often means "the beginning of the string," and is therefore unavailable for notating superscripts.

Comment: @Kevin Indeed: I’ve submitted an edit suggestion changing `^+` to `⁺` here to avoid that.

Comment: This is kind of like asking whether `a || b` and `a or b` are the same thing in the context of programming. The main difference is that different languages or authors use different ones (e.g. `||` in C++ and `or` in Python), and there may be small or big differences in how each language defines each of those things.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Although not used commonly, you can also use `or` in C++

Answer (score 5):

Usually that is a matter of taste. If I am nathematically motivated then I write $a^*$ like some single argument postfix operations in mathematics. If I keep close to applications, I would type $a*$ because typing superscripts in input for programs seems silly.

Same for $a^+$.

Be aware that in the context of regular expressions plus $+$ might have another meaning. It might be the same as "choice" or "union". Thus people can write $a+b$, $a\cup b$, or $a\mid b$ depending on their choice for that binary operator.

Comment: I would write $a^{+}b$ or `a+b`, but not $a+b$ or `a⁺b`.

Answer (score -1):

a* means that "a" must occur zero or more times.
a+ means that "a" most occur one or more times.

In other words, a* allows an empty string, while a+ doesn't (unless a itself allows an empty string).

To write it: If your editor allows it easily, $a^*$ and $a^+$ are preferable, because they are correct. On this site: Dollar, a, caret, star, dollar for $a^*$. Exponent in curly braces like { 15 } if it is more than a single character, like $a^{15}$ and not $a^15$.

PS. Oh well. I read your question as a+ vs a*. Maybe $a^+$ is not such a good idea. Or I need new glasses :-(